# Getting none and "[]" as a response for my webscraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am trying to scrape osu! stats from my friends profile, when I trying running the code I get "None" here is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests



html_text = requests.get('https://osu.ppy.sh/users/17906919').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
stats = soup.find_all('dl', class_ = 'profile-stats__entry')
print(stats)
```

Comment: Where you have written `soup.find_all('dl', class_ = 'profile-stats__entry')`,  what exactly do you expect that to mean? Did you try to verify that the source of the webpage makes sense for that search?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve my friends stats from a video game, the stats I'm trying to get are under that class

Comment: Are they under that class *in the source of the page*, i.e., before any Javascript runs? Have you *verified* this, for example by viewing the page in a web browser and going to "view source"?

Answer (score 1):

The desired data is actually presented within the `HTML` source under the following script tag"

```html
<script id="json-user" type="application/json">
```

So we would need to pickup it and parse it as JSON below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint as pp
import json


def main(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    goal = json.loads(soup.select_one('#json-user').string)
    pp(goal['statistics'])


main('https://osu.ppy.sh/users/17906919')
```

Output:

```
{'country_rank': 18133,
 'global_rank': 94334,
 'grade_counts': {'a': 159, 's': 99, 'sh': 9, 'ss': 6, 'ssh': 2},
 'hit_accuracy': 97.9691,
 'is_ranked': True,
 'level': {'current': 83, 'progress': 84},
 'maximum_combo': 896,
 'play_count': 9481,
 'play_time': 347925,
 'pp': 3868.29,
 'rank': {'country': 18133},
 'ranked_score': 715205885,
 'replays_watched_by_others': 0,
 'total_hits': 1086843,
 'total_score': 3896191620}
```

Comment: Could you explain this for me, it does work indeed but I would really like to know what it is actually doing.

Comment: @Alexisfunny actually it's picking up the following script tag `<script id="json-user" type="application/json">` and then parse it as `JSON`